# How to delete all the FOREIGN KEY Constraint?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 FOREGIN Keys in my table.

Here is my table:

```
create table rooms (
    room_id NUMBER(5)
    CONSTRAINT rooms_room_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    hotel_id NUMBER(10)
    CONSTRAINT rooms_hotel_id_fk REFERENCES hotel(hotel_id),
    avaliability VARCHAR2(10)
    CONSTRAINT rooms_avaliability_nn NOT NULL,
    staff_id NUMBER(10)
    CONSTRAINT rooms_staff_id_fk REFERENCES staffs(staff_id),
    room_type_id NUMBER(10)
    CONSTRAINT rooms_room_type_id_fk REFERENCES room_type(room_type_id)
)
/
```

I've been searching online on how to remove it but to no avail.

These are the codes I put in,

```
ALTER TABLE rooms
DROP CONSTRAINT room_type(room_type_id)
```

I want to remove the foreign key contraint but I keep getting invalid alter table option.
Any idea where I go wrong?

Comment: You have to specify the constraint names, e.g. rooms_room_type_id_fk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE rooms
DROP FOREIGN KEY room_type_id
```

This would work will drop the foreign key set on room_type_id